# How to know why my reputation is deducted?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Okay here is what happened. I logged into WPSE an hour ago and saw my reputation is 504 and have I got one more privilege. That was good and motivating. ;)

There was a questions that I flagged and then I commented on one more question. After 20 minutes when I visited WPSE again I saw I have lost -15 reputations. So, now I am just curious where I have lost them as my reputation page doesn't list the reason of -15 reputations. Though it lists previous deductions.

As you all know must have known by now that I am very new to WPSE and trying to get the hold of how WPSE works. Please don't take me wrong I am just curious and wanted to know why that happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My educated guess from the number (*15*) is that one of your accepted answers was un-accepted. Accepts are not set in stone, as there can be new circumstances or better answers provided. So technically you get reputation for accepted answer not for the moment it was accepted, but for as long as your answer stays accepted.

Comment: is there a way to know which answer got unaccepted? :)

Comment: @Hameedullah Khan: It appears this is very difficult or even impossible to do, because the system registers the vote when it is accepted, but later wipes out the vote when it is "unaccepted". After this you have no indication in the database what answer was and no longer is accepted. At least that is what I learn from the [main Meta Stack Overflow site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer) for the whole Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Thank you Rarst and Jan. Now I have rewrite related question waiting for both of you in WPSE. :)

Answer (score 2):

The [Reputation link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/reputation) will provide you with the answer you seek.  Clicking the recalc button will sort it out and add or remove any rep effected by moved or deleted questions.

Comment: +1 for the link.. its useful. But that doesn't tell why the reputation got deducted. I think @Rarst guess is right.

Comment: You can actually determine what question was responsible for the deduction.  Look for the number next to the deduction `16342 (-100)`  Take that number and add it to the end of this url: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions// and you will be able to see the question (if it still exists)

Comment: But I don't see any deduction for the last 3 days. Its all just +points. The only time I saw deduction was when I saw my points reduced and I clicked on my profile and the reputation tab was highlighted with -15.

Comment: Did you click recalc?

Comment: Yes, I did click.